# How to get type of geometry in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, geospatial

I'm working with the [geometry types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx) in SQL Server and I'm wondering if there's any function to tell what kind of geometry something is (point, multipoint, polygon, etc.)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you want [`STGeometryType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933825.aspx):

> The OGC type names that can be returned by STGeometryType() are Point, LineString, Polygon, GeometryCollection, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, and MultiPolygon.